# GWT won't deploy to Google

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Everytime I try to deploy my program to the google app engine it shows me this error, I hae googled it and have received no good answer. Can someone please tell me what this error is and how to fix it.

Compiling module com.romero.chapthree.GAEJChapThree
[ERROR] Unexpected
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: warningThreshold
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:340)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.(JdtCompiler.java:174)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:390)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:275)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:299)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:529)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:466)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:205)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:149)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:156)

Answer (score 6):

Try putting GWT classpath before any classpaths in your environment. Did you check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/t8qm22isWsg) thread?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is done in the project, GWT seems to be the problem because it does not even compile

Answer (score 0):

These days it appears you can fix it in the configuration of the gwt-maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0-1</version>
  <configuration>
    ...
    <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>

  </configuration>
```

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4479#c17
http://devnotesblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/maven-gwt-and-ecj/